# 403 forbidden .htaccess issue

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, ip, http-status-code-403

I have this .htaccess file in one directory on my site:

```
<limit GET> 
order deny,allow  
deny from all  
allow from 123.456.789
</limit>

ErrorDocument 403 403.html
```

It blocks everyone except for one IP. However, when an invalid IP visits, it does not show the 403.html file, but it just shows the text "403.html" on the page.

When I try to directly visit the 403.html page on the directory, it gets the same message too.

Answer (score 0):

ErrorDocument requires a full path, i.e `ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html` to work. It also takes HTML which is why it was showing that text.

Comment: Still have nothing, I put in `ErrorDocument 403 /403.php` and nothing happened.

Comment: Try just a static HTML file for it.